# How to GET Git Commits by User

Tags: git, get

I would like to know if there is a way using either the GitHub or GitLab (Preferably the latter) API's to get commits by user? e.g To retrieve the last commit made by a user.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58197588/960623 (in short, github has now a "commits" API that allows you to search for user's commit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git log --author="that user"

--author Only show commits in which the author entry matches the specified string.

https://git-scm.com/book/ch2-3.html

http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/07/18/filtering-by-author-name/